# Fade in/out music on clicking anchor link

Tags: jquery, audio, anchor, fade

I have a webpage with several links that will fade in pages when clicked, instead of loading a different .html file.
This is my code:

```
<!--fade and show windows-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.aboutbutton').click(function() {
            displayNone();
            showWindow("aboutpage");
        } );
        ....
        ....  
        function displayNone() {
            $('#homepage,#aboutpage,#blueprintpage,#budgetpage,#musicpage').fadeOut();
        }
        function showWindow(name) {
            $('#' + name).fadeIn();
        }

    });
</script>
...
...
<body>

    <a href="#aboutpage" class="aboutbutton">About</a>
    <a href="#blueprintpage" class="blueprintbutton">Blueprint</a>
    ...
    ...
    <div id="aboutpage">  
               //CONTENT OF THIS PAGE//
    </div>
    <div id="blueprintpage">              
               //CONTENT OF THIS PAGE//
    </div>
    ....
    ....
    <!--simple pause/play music button at bottom of page using flash-->
    <div class="backgroundmusic">
        <span class="whitetext backgroundmusictext">Background music </span>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="25" height="20"
        codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="../site/swf/singlemp3player.swf?file=../site/music/OST/wenqing.mp3&backColor=990000&frontColor=ddddff&repeatPlay=true&autoStart=true&songVolume=30" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <embed wmode="transparent" width="25" height="20" src="../site/swf/singlemp3player.swf?file=../site/music/OST/wenqing.mp3&backColor=990000&frontColor=ddddff&repeatPlay=true&autoStart=true&songVolume=30"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see each page is accessed through an anchor link. I want to assign a background music to each page. When any link (like "about" "blueprint" etc) is clicked, I want any music that is currently playing to fade out, then a new music fades in.

This is a personal music website and all the music are my works, and none of them are the eardrum-destroying mainstream stuff, they're all calm piano melodies, so please don't comment about "terrible idea to have background music" etc etc.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it ***is*** a terrible idea to have background music.  If I have music playing, background music is the last thing I want to hear.

Comment: Love the fact you read his caveat at the end before commenting ;)

Comment: Then perhaps you have had your eardrums destroyed by mainstream garbage already. That's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to have background music playing, I'd suggest a javascript based music framework called [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). You can control the playing of the music much more easily, as well as support newer HTML5 playback for people with flash disabled. Then use something like the code posted on [the GetSatisfaction page for the same issue](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/fade_in_out):

```
function fadeInSound(soundID,amount) {
  var s = soundManager.getSoundById(soundID);
  var vol = s.volume;
  if (vol == 100) return false;
  s.setVolume(Math.min(100,vol+amount));
  setTimeout(function(){fadeInSound(soundID,amount)},20);
}

function fadeOutSound(soundID,amount) {
  var s = soundManager.getSoundById(soundID);
  var vol = s.volume;
  if (vol == 0) return false;
  s.setVolume(Math.max(0,vol+amount));
  setTimeout(function(){fadeOutSound(soundID,amount)},20);
}
```

Essentially, you just decrease / increase the volume of the sound a fixed amount over a certain interval.